# Get Smart Table Binding Model SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I was trying to get the model data of Smart Table(Combination of Smart Filter and Smart Table). But I am not able to trace it. My Smart Table data is coming from OData entityset. I want to get the table data. Please suggest.

Regards
Karthik S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT

Bounded data can be grabbed in  [`dataReceived`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable/events/dataReceived) event:

Controller.js:

```
onDataReceived: function(oControlEvent) {
    var itemCount = oControlEvent.getParameters().getParameter('data')['results'].length;
}
```

View.xml:

```
    <smartTable:SmartTable
            dataReceived="onDataReceived" ... >
```

Also this will be called each time the Go button has been pressed in the filterBar.

Underlying table can be accessed with smartTable's [`getTable()`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable/methods/getTable) method. 
Depend on the type of the underlying table, for

- `sap.m.Table` [`getItems()`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/methods/getItems)
- `sap.ui.table.Table` [`getRows()`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table/methods/getRows)

can be used to get the content of the aggregation.